# In the main method, why can we call the constructor of the same class?

Tags: java, constructor, program-entry-point

This just contrasts with my understandings. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Java doesn't allow static-reference to non-static methods, but we call constructor method from main method all the time... I'm assuming constructors are implicitly non-static here.

```
    public class Temp {
        // Constructor
        public Temp(){
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Calling constructor within main method
            Temp tmp = new Temp();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example to help illustrate what you're asking?

Comment: Please show your code here

Comment: although not explicitly stated, constructor methods are static.

Comment: It sounds like you missunderstood something.

Comment: Can you give one single reason why you shouldn't be able to call it?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher They are *not* 'technically static', and the evidence is that you can use `this` inside them.

Comment: @user207421, constructor methods are static in the sense they do not require an instance to be invoked from (and they may be invoked from static methods). one may say constructor is a special case of static method.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher One might equally well say they are special instances of non-static methods for the opposite reasons. It isn't helpful either way. They are just special methods with their own restrictions, which curiously enough is  exactly what the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8) says. No need to make things up, and certainly no need to invent a new category of static methods that can have `this` inside them.

Comment: I just edited my question. Sorry for the confusions.

Answer (score 0):

it is the combination of both new and constructor, the reason behind allowing the constructor calling in main method.
if suppose,
create a Constructor:

**public SampleTest(){}**

calling it from main method:

**Scenario 1:** if i directly calling that constructor from main method without new keyword::

```
    SampleTest();
```

**Result 1:** it is throwing the compile time exception **"The method SampleTest() is undefined for the type SampleTest"**

**Scenario 2:** if i created a method named SampleTest() in that class as shown below(which has return type as void, as we don't have return types for constructors):

```
  public void SampleTest() {}

  public static void main(String[] args){
    SampleTest();
  }
```

**Result 2:** it is throwing the compile time exception **"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method SampleTest() from the type SampleTest"**

**Scenario 3:** now if add new keyword before constructor calling as shown below:

```
  new  SampleTest();
```

**Result 3:** so now only with the combination of **new** operator with **constructor** calling is allowed in main method, with out showing any exception.

So finally, the reason behind the constructor calling from the main method is the combination of new and constructor. otherwise it considers the constructor as any other instance method, throws exceptions as in Result 1 and 2.